# Windows _EPROCESS Structure

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-kernel

Is there any source to find details of each field in `_EPROCESS` structure? I'm working on a `VM` introspection project where I try to get detailed information of each running process. I can read the data for each fields but I don't really know what those fields represent. I couldn't find any link explaining those fields, probably because `Windows` being a closed source `OS`.

I understand that I might not be able to find details of each and every fields but it would really help me if I can get at least some of them.

Comment: I would start here to understand the structure. MSDN/technetium also have there versions. I think this one at least shows it a little better. http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/EPROCESS.html

Answer (score 1):

EPROCESS is a structure very internal to the operating system kernel and changes quite a lot accross individual Windows versions. That's another reason why it is not documented. It would be probably better if you write down the fields you are interested in. Maybe, somebody would know their meaning. In some cases, the meaning can be guessed from their names.

Keep also in mind that access to certain fields may be synchronized via a lock so you may receive inconsistend data when reading them without acquiring the lock.

If you are interested in information that is available via certain kernel API (e.g. `PSXxx` routines), you can reverse the API and decode their references into EPROCESS and other structures.